# How to multiply two long values in java

Tags: java, multiplication

I am trying to multiply two largest numbers from an array of numbers. Its working fine for small numbers.

Correct input / output - this is working:

3 10 2 8 
   80

Correct input / output - this is failing:

```
2 100000 90000
9000000000
```

My output is however 10000000000 instead.

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
public static Long sumPairwise(Long[] numbers){

        int index=0;
        int n = numbers.length;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            if(numbers[i]>numbers[index])
                    index=i;
        }
        numbers[n-1]= numbers[index];
        index=0;
        for(int j=1;j<n-1;j++){
        if(numbers[j]>numbers[index])
                index=j;
        }
        numbers[n-2]=numbers[index];
        Long product = (numbers[n-2])*(numbers[n-1]);

    return product ;
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    Long numbers[] = new Long[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    numbers[i]= sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println(sumPairwise(numbers));

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the original number in that index with another number. 
That is causing the issue.

Please just simply find the max 2 numbers from below logic and multiply. 
Also, remember to close scanner.

Here the simple solution. This will work only for positive integers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Snippet {
        public static long multiplyHighestTwoValues(Long[] numbers) {

            long maxOne = 0;
            long maxTwo = 0;
            for (long n : numbers) {
                if (maxOne < n) {
                    maxTwo = maxOne;
                    maxOne = n;
                } else if (maxTwo < n) {
                    maxTwo = n;
                }
            }

            long product = maxOne * maxTwo;
            return product;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            Long numbers[] = new Long[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                numbers[i] = sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(sumPairwise(numbers));
            sc.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not close a scanner tied to `System.in`, as it closes the underlying resource, namely `System.in`. Only close resources you have opened yourself. `System.in` is managed by the JVM.

Comment: Yes. there was a bug. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in your code: `numbers[n-1]` may well contain the second highest number. You are overwriting that number with the highest number in your code, before you try and put it at the first to last position.

One way to overcome this is to sort the array using `Arrays.sort`, this way you are sure that the last two numbers are the highest and second highest number.

```
public static long multiplyLargestTwoNumbers(long[] numbers) {
    long[] sortedNumbers = numbers.clone();
    Arrays.sort(sortedNumbers);

    int size = numbers.length;
    // multiply highest and second highest number
    return sortedNumbers[size - 1] * sortedNumbers[size - 2];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    long numbers[] = new long[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        numbers[i] = sc.nextLong();
    }
    System.out.println(multiplyLargestTwoNumbers(numbers));
}
```

---

Other changes:

- using `long` instead of `Long`: try and use primitive types when the objective reference types are not needed (you need `Long` if you want to use e.g. a `List` because a `List` can only hold object references);
- spaced out `for` loops, please use white space;
- renamed method, as it does't add anything pairwise;
- used curly braces for `for` loop in main method;
- removed spurious parentheses in part that performs multiplication.

You might also introduce an `if` statement that first checks if the `numbers` array does indeed contain at least two elements. This is called a *guard statement*.

Finally remember that `byte`, `short` and `long` all contain signed numbers of a specific bit size. Basically you are performing calculations *modulus 2^n* where n is the bit size. If the value is too large it may overflow and return an incorrect result. For that you need `BigInteger`.

Comment: I'll leave it here for the good code practices and the clear problem description, the [solution of Narayan Parvatikar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026277/589259) is the technically better solution as it doesn't alter the array.

Comment: Yes. there was a bug. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers (and upvote the ones that have been helpful). For just two numbers the answer of Narayan is better in my opinion, the `Array.sort` method scales better (in case you want to multiply the last 3 or 4 instead of the last 2.

Comment: What is the use of clone()

Comment: Generally you don't want a method to have side effects. Note that the array is passed by reference, so the array would be sorted *outside the method* as well. That's not something you would expect when calling this function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Long` try to use `BigInteger` to multiply larger values that fit into `long`, otherwise your result may *overflow*.

Use `BigDecimal` instead for multiplying floating point numbers.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, the numbers she is using will work with long data type. BigInteger is not required. The program is not failing because of its data type. It just has a bug.

Comment: @NarayanParvatikar There is no difference regarding value range between long and Long. Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: Precision is the wrong word, you probably meant: *range*.

Comment: @GhostCat I am telling that instead of BigInteger we could use long/ Long. Hope you get it.

Comment: @NarayanParvatikar You didn't say that before, that is the difference. Subtle details matter ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately the problem description in the question was not all that clear: it didn't specify how the second input was failing. Therefore this was a good guess, but it doesn't solve the issue within the question: the bug in the code where the last element was replaced even if it is the second highest number is not caught by this answer, and therefore the answer is wrong.